# see if changing html fails in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Its sounds simple, but let me explain.
I make ajax calls to update the body content and I want to alert if the updating fails in the client side, I mean after receiving response from ajax and if it fails of anycase.

```
$(".body").html(response_from_ajax) ;
```

so I tried with my basic knowledge like this

```
if ( ! $(".body").html(response_from_ajax) )
{
alert('error');
}
```

this is not working.

Comment: what kind of failure are you expecing

Comment: if any over talented users change/remove class of body, so thats a failure case Im expecting now, and may be if jquery fails due to any conflict or some thing like that

Comment: jQuery ajax methods has native success and error cases: `var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" ).done(function() { alert( "success" ); }).fail(function() { alert( "error" ); }).always(function() { alert( "complete" );});`. Read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and adapt it to your poorly-described scenario.

Comment: You might want to have a look at JavaScript [Try... Catch functionality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Comment: `.html()` is a function which is not supposed to possibly fail. It is not an, for instance, HTTP request - it will definitely always work... **except** for some exceptional cases. That's why we got **exceptions** in many programming languages including JavaScript. Read about it.

Comment: You are failing to handle errors because you are trying to deal with them at the wrong place.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it can fail after getting the content from ajax call because you are just setting the html of the div. However, you can simply define the error method in the ajax call to make sure that data is recieved from the ajax call.